# cat files together with newline in shellscript

Tags: shell, cat

I am cating files together recursively in a directory, however, some files are missing a newline after the last line, so this creates a problem.  
How do I append a newline to each file in the process?  here's the shellscript

```
    find $1 -type f |xargs cat  > test.csv
```

Answer (score 5):

I realize this is a fairly old question, but I had the same problem. None of the answers above seemed to work with files with whitespace in them, because of the usage of backticks and /usr/bin/find. Doing so would require me to change $IFS which is absolutely not necessary unless you only need to use files.

This is my take on it:

```
for i in *; do cat "$i" && echo ""; done
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a loop:

```
find $1 -type f | while IFS= read -r file
do
    cat "$file"
    echo
done > test.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a for-loop:

```
for file in $(find .); do cat $file >> huge_file; echo " " >> huge_file; done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
find $1 -type f |xargs awk 'FNR==1 && NR>1 {print ""} {print}'
```

or

```
find $1 -type f |xargs awk 'ENDFILE {print ""} {print}'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to add a newline for any file that does not have a newline on its own as the last line, you can do the following:

```
for f in `find $1 -type f`; do sed -E '$s/(.*\S+.*)/\1\n/' $f; done
```

EDIT: My first answer used xargs, but that didn't provide the expected result, so fell back on a loop.